# Transaction data aggregate

Tags: sql-server

As a disclaimer, I am not entirely sure the title of the question is best, if not I apologize.

I am trying to calculate cycle times for individuals, but files are occasionally transferred out of their work queues and eventually back.   There are no unique transaction IDs recorded just a date and time stamp.

I tried looking for an aggregate group by functions and was told that is not a feature sql-server has.

I started by trying to identify the first and last transaction and was going to build out the query from there but it wasn't too helpful.  Any insight would be very helpful.

Changedate is when the transfer from one person to another is recorded (year, moth, day time)

```
select a.claimId,
       a.claimincidentID,
       cast(a.changeDate as date) changedate,
       a.claimNum,
       a.Coverage,
       a.AssignedAdjID, 
       a.AssignedAdj,
       a.AssignedUnit,
       a.TransferedAdjID,
       a.TransferedAdj,
       a.TransferedUnit,
       a.usertypeid,
       a.ChangedBy,
       b.Feature_Create_Date,
       DATEDIFF(day, b.Feature_Create_Date, a.changedate) transfer1,
       cast(FIRST_VALUE(changeDate) OVER (ORDER BY changedate ASC)as date) AS firstchangedate,
       cast(LAST_VALUE(changeDate) OVER (ORDER BY a.changedate ASC)as date) AS lastchangedate 
from DB1.dbo.Assign_Transfer a
left join DB2.claimslist b on a.claimid=b.claimId 
group by a.claimId, a.claimincidentID, a.changeDate, a.claimNum, a.Coverage, a.AssignedAdjID, a.AssignedAdj, a.AssignedUnit, a.TransferedAdjID, a.TransferedAdj, a.TransferedUnit, a.usertypeid, a.ChangedBy, b.Feature_Create_Date
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: @DanielBlais this sql statement can't be for mysql, I changed the tag to sql server.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Does a.changeDate have a DateTime type, so that we can sequence these when multiple changes happen during a day?  Is  {a.claimId,}  OR  {a.claimId, a.claimincidentID,} the proper level that should be tracked?  (or more granular?)  Any sample data for these two tables?  For that sample data, what results do you expect?

Comment: @daniel, Sql Server, sorry.  seanLange, claimID and ClaimincidentID interchangeable, I include them both because if I need to join other tables then they're both there.

Comment: @donPablo No, the claimid and claimincidentId are the same thing.

Comment: For a claimID chain, the row with the earliest changeDate, is the ID of the first person in the AssignedAdjID or in the TransferedAdjID ?? What do these represent for the first row?

Comment: Each row has an assignedadjID, who the claim is currently assigned to, then transferadjID who the claim is being transferred.  My output keeps separating each transfer.  So A > b, B>C, C>A, then A closes the file.   My issue is calculating the true cycle-time for A.  I was using claim create date, but that doesn't truly represent the working-time that A would have it.  Does that answer your question?   Unfortunately, this is the most unique identifier that we store.  I don't know if the functions needed are available in SQLserver.

Comment: What is in the AssignedAdjID of the first record in a claim chain? Null? "Central Casting" ?   It would seem that First_Value and Last_Value might not be meaningful when so many columns are in the GroupBy.

Comment: @donPablo The AssignedTo is an adjuster's unit queue.  For example, if I were in the unit TotalLoss, the original row would be  "assignedAdj=TL" , "TransferAdj = asfx"    I will upload example data shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Think of each of these rows as a Start (because the most recent one hasn't ended)
We would need to generate the complement End for this person in the chain.
Then with pairs of Start/End one could create GrossDuration.

Even after we get an assignment's start and end date/time,
we will have workday (8-4, or 9-5, or noon-8, ...) considerations, 
also Sat/Sun/Hol and Vacation/out-of-office.  
All of which affect Duration--- For Each Person differently.
Which would need to be factored by workday/etc into AdjDuration.

Lets say we can sequence these 
 Row_Number() Over (Partition by claimID Order by changeDate) as tfrNum
Assigned is the prior, and Transfered is the next
1, 2, 3, ... thru  N
                   V
             a.changeDate                 -- NOW()
                   V                          V
a.AssignedAdjID,   |  a.TransferedAdjID,
a.AssignedAdj,     |  a.TransferedAdj,
a.AssignedUnit,    |  a.TransferedUnit,
                   |
             a.usertypeid,
             a.ChangedBy,

So, is tfrNum=1 or tfrNum=N the oddball??
Lets look at pairs: each pair goes StartFrom->EndTo
1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6, 6-Now

----
From row1 we get TransferredID Start(changeDate) and 
from row2 we get AssignedAdjID End  (changeDate)
-- 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, etc repeating
--except for
From row6 we get TransferredID Start(changeDate) and
from default  (still them)  End  (Now)
-- -- except again when TransferredUnit is "Closed"
```

After getting these pairs and their Start and End, we can do the Duration calc.

I need to visualize this problem before I try to run some sql.  Real data would help.

Lets start with this, and later I would expand on it after you get it working and look at some data--

```
With cte_tfrNum (claimID, changeDate, tfrNum, tfrMax) AS
(
    SELECT
         a.claimId
        ,a.changeDate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() Over ( Partition By a.claimId Order By a.changeDate) as tfrNum
        ,b.tfrMax
    FROM  DB1.dbo.Assign_Transfer a
    -- just for giggles, lets also get the max# of transfers for this claim
    Left Join 
          (SELECT claimId, COUNT(*) as tfrMax
           FROM  DB1.dbo.Assign_Transfer 
           Group By claimId
           ) as b
    On b.claimId = a.claimId
)

-- Statement using the CTE  
Select
    tfrTo.*
From cte_tfrNum as tfrTo
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I was able to take what you gave me and add a few things to be able to look at what I needed.

```
select 
case when abc.tfrMax > abc.tfrnum then datediff(day,lag(abc.changedate) over(partition by abc.claimID order by abc.claimId),abc.changeDate)
     when abc.tfrMax = abc.tfrnum then datediff(day,lag(abc.changedate) over(partition by abc.claimID order by abc.claimId),abc.changeDate)
end as test
, abc.*
from
(
SELECT
         a.claimId
        ,a.changeDate
        ,a.AssignedAdj
        ,a.TransferedAdj
        ,a.Coverage
        ,ROW_NUMBER() Over ( Partition By a.claimId Order By a.changeDate) as tfrNum
        ,b.tfrMax
    FROM  db1.dbo.Assign_Transfer a
    Left Join 
          (SELECT claimId, COUNT(*) as tfrMax
           FROM  db1.dbo.Assign_Transfer 
           Group By claimId
           ) as b
    On b.claimId = a.claimId
) abc   
group by 
         abc.claimId
        ,abc.changeDate
        ,abc.AssignedAdj
        ,abc.TransferedAdj
        ,abc.Coverage
        ,abc.tfrMax
        ,abc.tfrNum
```